# MsSQL: Find accounts that dropped during a historical range

Tags: sql-server

I have a database that has the following columns:

```
ReportMonth, AccountID, Status
```

Each month a report runs that fills in data for the AccountID and Status for the given month. However, it is a known issue that occasionally the report does not populate a status for an account (even when it should be).

I'd like to design a query to find these "dropped" accounts, and report all of the months they've been missing. As an example, say I have account 123 reported for Jan 2014 (and some previous months). Now it's June 2014, and I haven't got any record of account 123 for February, March, etc. I'd like a list of that states the months this account has been missing for, like so:

```
ReportMonth, AccountID, MissingSince, LastStatus
```

Thus far I've been able to find accounts that dropped off in comparison to the last month by using a left join and searching for nulls like so:

```
left outer join #StatusCodes b on a.AccountID= b.AccountID
and datediff(m,0,a.ReportMonth) = datediff(m,0,b.ReportMonth)-1
...
and b.AccountID is null
```

But this obviously only works for one month only.

[SQL Fiddle for what I'm doing now](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38b0f/3/0)

Should output a 1 for Report Months between Feb and April, and 2 for May onwards. Ie:

```
ReportMonth | Dropped Accounts
Jan 2014.   | 0
Feb 2014.   | 1
March 2014. | 1
Apr 2014.   | 1
May 2014.   | 2
Jun 2014.   | 2
```

[Updated SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3841/1) <-- My eventual implementation. The small data set doesn't do it justice, but it works!

Comment: Could you post some sample input and required output ? or sqlfiddle 'd help!

Comment: Added! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38b0f/3/0

Comment: It's not clear to me what are you trying to get. Just the missing count?, Can you post some sample input and output?

Comment: Sorry, editing on a phone is quite difficult. Example input in the fiddle, output in the last bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started...

Isolate all `distinct` values for month/account, then `cross apply` them, then compare to the `reportHist` table and populate a 1/0 for missing rows via a `CASE` and `SUM()` the results.

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/38b0f/4).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TEMPDB..#reportHist') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #reportHist

CREATE TABLE #reportHist
    (
     ReportMonth datetime, 
     AccountID varchar(20), 
     Status varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO #reportHist
(ReportMonth, AccountID, Status)
VALUES
('1-1-2014','123','Good'),
('1-1-2014','999','Good'),
('2-1-2014','999','Bad'),
('3-1-2014','999','Good'),
('4-1-2014','999','Good');

;WITH DistinctAccount
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT AccountID
FROM #reportHist
)
, DistinctMonth
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT ReportMonth
FROM #reportHist
)

SELECT DM.ReportMonth, SUM(CASE WHEN RH.AccountID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [Dropped Accounts]
FROM DistinctAccount DA
CROSS APPLY DistinctMonth DM
LEFT OUTER JOIN #reportHist RH
   ON DA.AccountID = RH.AccountID
   AND DM.ReportMonth = RH.ReportMonth  
GROUP BY DM.ReportMonth
```

Comment: I think this does help out a lot, I wasn't sure how to use cross apply here. I had thought to take the distinct months and apply there, but here it's the reverse. I'll try it and see if I can't get your method to work. :)

Comment: [Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a3841/1)  I adapted the code to ignore accounts that hadn't appeared yet, and to ignore cases where it was expected an account to disappear. Unfortunately, the SQLFiddle doesn't really show it working all that well (I blame the small dataset), but it works!